# How determine the PID of a process that was started by instantiating a COM coclass?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

Is there any way to determine the PID of a process that was started by instantiating a COM coclass?

For example:

```
MyApp.ApplicationClass anApp = new MyApp.ApplicationClass();
```

would start the process *myapp*. Potentially there are already a lot of *myapp* processes running when this code is executed.

My current solution to acquire the latest PID feels a bit awkward: I memorize the list of running processes before creating the new instance and take the delta of running *myapp* PIDs when the new instance was created.

Is there an standard/better way to accomplish this?

**Edit**: The PID is later used to identify/monitor the created process.

Comment: It might help if you add why you want the PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also control the code for `MyApp` ?

If so, I'd recommend the best way to do this is to add a method to MyApp called `GetPid()`, and just call `anApp.GetPid()`...

Comment: +1 Thanks, good hint! It wouldn't be impossible to convince the code owners to provide an additional method or interface, however, if possible I would prefer a non-intrusive solution.

Comment: Despite other input, I honor your creative suggestion and accept your answer. In the end I used this intrusive solution. However, I would still have preferred a non-intrusive solution... But perhaps there is none :-)